# Set a class with helpers in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, helper

im doing a webapp with meteor and i would like to apply a class of active in an li element if the value of it is equal to a variable from a Session variable called ('month')

```html
<template name="Navbar">    
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="{{active}}"><a href="#myPage">Janvier</a></li>
    <li class="{{active}}"><a href="#">Février</a></li>
    <li class="{{active}}"><a href="#">Mars</a></li>
    <li class="{{active}}"><a href="#">Avril</a></li>
    <li class="{{active}}"><a href="#">Mai</a></li>
    <li class="{{active}}"><a href="#">Juin</a></li>
    <li class="{{active}}"><a href="#">Juillet</a></li>
    <li class="{{active}}"><a href="#">Août</a></li>
    <li class="{{active}}"><a href="#">Septembre</a></li>
    <li class="{{active}}"><a href="#">Octobre</a></li>
    <li class="{{active}}"><a href="#">Novembre</a></li>
    <li class="{{active}}"><a href="#">Décembre</a></li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

My variable session gives me a month and i would like with a helper to put the class "active" to it if the innerHtml is equal to the session variable. I don't know how to retrieve the value of "this" innerHtml.

```js
Template.Navbar.helpers({
  active: function() {
    if(Session.get("month") === this.value) {
      return "active";
      }
  }
});
```

Thank u for the help .

Yoann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a variable into your helper class and compare with your Session variable.

```
<template name="Navbar">    
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="{{active 'Janvier'}}"><a href="#myPage">Janvier</a></li>
     ...
  </ul>
</template>
```

In your Template you can use the variable.

```
Template.Navbar.helpers({
      active: function(month) {
        if(Session.get("month") === month) {
          return "active";
          }
      }
    });
```